# I there anyway that I can build the web in one docker container and deploy it in another docker container?

Tags: javascript, docker, nginx, docker-compose

You know I am now trying to build the web in one docker container and use volume to get the dist after build, and start the nginx container to deploy the dist folder.
This is the docker-compose script:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jump-ui-build:
    image: node:12.13.0
    volumes:
      - ~/jump-ui:/usr/local/app
    working_dir: /usr/local/app
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    command: bash -c "npm install && npm run build:test"

  nginx:
    restart: always
    image: nginx:1.16.1
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - ~/jump-ui/dist:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ~/nginx-log:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - jump-ui-build
```

the jump-ui-build service run and finish successfully and generate the dist folder under the jump-ui folder, but when I try "docker exec -it" to access the nginx service and switch to /usr/share/nginx/html, it is the empy folder, so I have to manually start the jump-ui-build service and start the nginx service, and it deploy successfully?

Is there anyway to modify the yum script that I can successfully build and deploy the web automatically?

Comment: Not sure you want docker-compose for something like this. What you can do is use a [multi-stage build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) using multiple docker images to build then deploy. See this example from Vue ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

Comment: @Phil  I read the page before, but you know the tutorial is not my expecation, it build and deploy in the same container,I just wanna seperate them into two docker container, one is for build, one is for deploy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use `multistage` Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.13.0
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
RUN bash -c "npm install && npm run build:test"

FROM nginx:1.16.1
COPY --from=0 /usr/local/app /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80 443
```

this way you will end up with one `nginx` image, build it :

```
docker build -t my_image .
```

your compose should be:

```
nginx:
    restart: always
    image: my_image
    ports: 
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - $HOME/nginx-log:/var/log/nginx
```

Comment: what should I do to put the "docker build -t " into docker compose before I execute docker compose up  -d?

Comment: you can build the dockerfile in your compose if you do not want to start the image , using `build:` directive instead of `image:` and then use `docker-compose up -d --build`

Comment: I mean I wanna use one script docker-compose up -d to start the image, the sequence is build the web first and then deploy, only use one script, thanks!

Comment: For better reading: You can write `FROM node:12.13.0 AS builder` and then `COPY --from=builder`